# java- how to convert a ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> into String[]][]

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I want to store some data in an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` variable into a csv file.

For this purpose, I zeroed in on Ostermiller Utilities- which include a CSV Writer as well.

The problem is, the csvwrite functionality requires a String, String[] or a `String[][]` variable.

I wont know beforehand the number of rows/columns in my ArrayList of arraylists-- so how do I use the above (cswrite) functionality? Dont I have to declare a fixed size for a `String[]][]` variable?

Answer (score 3):

A `String[][]` is nothing more than an array of arrays. For example, this makes a 'triangular matrix' using a 2d array. It doesn't have to be a square (although CSV probably should be square, it doesn't have to be).

```
String[][] matrix = new String[][5];    

matrix[0] = new String[1];
matrix[1] = new String[2];
matrix[2] = new String[3];
matrix[3] = new String[4];
matrix[4] = new String[5];
```

So for your purposes

```
String[][] toMatrix(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOFLists) {
    String[][] matrix = new String[][listOfLists.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        matrix[i]= listOfLists.get(i).toArray();
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Just keep in mind that in this case, it's in `matrix[col][row]`, not `matrix[row][col]`. You may need to transpose this result, depending on the needs of your library.

Comment: the problem is that I dont want to set a fixed size-- viz new String[][5] -- AFAIK you have to declare atleast one dimension of a String[][]? thanks...

Comment: Yes you have to delcare one dimension - that dimension is however long your master list is.

Comment: Beat me to the punch, great answer!

Comment: In your solution you need to switch the initializer in the brackets, it should be "new String[listOfLists.size()][];". The same problem is in the example, should be "String [][] matrix = new String[5][];"

Comment: Check for null is missing (-;

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of arrays (matrix) with one size at first, and then iterate and add the data as you traverse the list of list

```
String[][] arr = new String[listOfList.size()][];
int i = 0;
for (List<String> row: listOfList) {
    arr[i++] = row.toArray(new String[row.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working:

```
        String[][] arrayOfArraysOfString = new String[arrayListOfArrayListsOfStrings.size()][];

    for (int index = 0; index < arrayListOfArrayListsOfStrings.size(); index++) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayListOfString = arrayListOfArrayListsOfStrings.get(index);
        if (arrayListOfString != null) {
            arrayOfArraysOfString[index] = arrayListOfString.toArray(new String[arrayListOfString.size()]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example of how to convert your multidimesional ArrayList into a multidimensional String Array.

```
package stuff;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> multidimesionalArrayList = createArrayListContent(); 
    String[][] multidimensionalStringArray = new String[multidimesionalArrayList.size()][];
    int index = 0;

    for (ArrayList<String> strings : multidimesionalArrayList) {
        multidimensionalStringArray[index] = strings.toArray(new String[]{}); 
        index++;
    }

    System.out.println(multidimensionalStringArray);
}

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> createArrayListContent() throws Exception  {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    result.add(createArrayList());
    result.add(createArrayList());
    result.add(createArrayList());
    result.add(createArrayList());
    result.add(createArrayList());
    return result;
}

private static ArrayList<String> createArrayList() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    Thread.sleep(10);
    list.add(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    Thread.sleep(10);
    list.add(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    Thread.sleep(10);
    list.add(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    Thread.sleep(10);
    list.add(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    return list;
}
```

}